# In port forwarding, is the ultimate destination decided solely by the intermediary entity?

Tags: ssh, proxy, port-forwarding

In [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding), is the ultimate destination to connect to solely decided by the intermediary entity which provides port forwarding, not by an application client?

Although the page mentions [dynamic port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding#Dynamic_port_forwarding) (such as provided by SSH), is it correct that dynamic port forwarding isn't port forwarding, because its ultimate destination is decided by application client itself not by the intermediary entity? Is dynamic port forwarding not port forwarding, but proxy?

Thanks.

A complement to [What are the relations and differences between port forwarding and proxy?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498849/what-are-the-relations-and-differences-between-port-forwarding-and-proxy) to understand their differences.

Comment: A very general networking question. Perhaps there is another SE site you could post this on?

Comment: not that i am aware of

Comment: A static port forwarder means "connect to local port, any traffic is forward to a remote port".   SSH 'dynamic port forwarding' is a proxy server; the client needs to talk the proxy protocol to tell the ssh server where to connect to.  After that it forwards the traffic to the remote port.

Answer (score 1):

> In port forwarding, is the ultimate destination ... solely decided by the intermediary entity which provides port forwarding, not by an application client?

Correct (assuming the destination dose not decide to pass it on, etc)

> Although the page mentions dynamic port forwarding (such as provided by SSH), is it correct that dynamic port forwarding isn't port forwarding, because its ultimate destination is decided by application client itself not by the intermediary entity? Is dynamic port forwarding not port forwarding, but proxy?

Correct, but the definitions are often necessarily blurry due to functionality overlap so don't put to much weight on classifying the implementation of the concept.

> What are the relations and differences between port forwarding and proxy? to help me understand their differences.

What you just said "ultimate destination is decided by application"